# Eclipse Error but doesnt show where

Tags: android, eclipse

My Pc hung and and had to hard restart the Pc and all of a sudden there is this new icon on the project..

[image]

But eclipse doesnt show what the error is in the code.

Comment: Have you tried doing a Clean and then rebuild?

Comment: yeah i have. guess one of the external jar was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the project and select Properties.
Check under Java Build Path and check the different tabs there.

When a resource is connected to your app that suddenly goes missing (missing folders, libaries etc) but it's not project-breaking, it shows up like that as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot.. i had added an external jar and somehow it was missing from the location. thanks a lot